# Simple SOAP progam

Tags: java, php, python, soap

I have to do a simple scritp (unix/linux target) to close log_file of a print spooler program

the spooler program give the chances to call the function over soap, but I know nothing of it

this is the function:

```
- <!--  VPSX System Close Account file Command request 
  --> 
- <message name="VPSX_SystemCloseAcct">
  <part name="SessID" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <part name="VPSID" type="xsd:string" /> 
  </message>


- <!--  VPSX System close account file Command request/response 
  --> 
- <operation name="VPSX_SystemCloseAcct">
  <input message="lrs:VPSX_SystemCloseAcct" /> 
  <output message="lrs:VPSX_SystemCmdResponse" /> 
  </operation>


<!--  VPSX System close account file Command request/response 
  --> 
- <operation name="VPSX_SystemCloseAcct">
  <soap:operation soapAction="" /> 
- <input>
  <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://www.lrs.com"
encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" /> 
  </input>
- <output>
  <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://www.lrs.com"
encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" /> 
  </output>
  </operation>
```

is there a simple way (python?php?java?) to do this?

I've tryed in perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use SOAP::Lite;

my $WSDL= 'http://myserver:81/lrs/webconnect/vpsx?trid=vpsx';

my $soap = SOAP::Lite->on_fault(\&SoapFault)
                        ->service($WSDL);

my $logon = $soap->Logon
(
   SOAP::Data->type('string')->name('Server')->value("VSVK1"),
   SOAP::Data->type('string')->name('UserID')->value("serv"),
   SOAP::Data->type('string')->name('Password')->value("serv")
);

$sessionID = $logon->result();

#my $chiusura = $soap->VPSX_SystemCloseAcct
#(
#   SOAP::Data->type('string')->name('SessID')->value($sessionID),
#   SOAP::Data->type('string')->name('VPSID')->value("") 
#);

my $logoff = $soap->Logoff
( 
  SOAP::Data->type('string')->name('SessID')->value($sessionID)
);
```

but obtain this error

```
String value expected instead of SOAP::Data reference
```

Comment: if you want to send soap request you can do it over java there is a soapui jar

Comment: I have to use it over script bash scheduling it

Comment: try to use soap ui (http://www.soapui.org/) and see if you can run it using command line

Comment: installed soapui...connected to wdsl and displayed all the SOAP function...but I don't understand how to test them or change them into script :O((

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this URL
http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/integrating-with-junit.html

JUnit Integration

It is fairly easy to invoke the testrunner from your own JUnit-tests;

public void testRunner() throws Exception 
{
  SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner(); 
  runner.setProjectFile( "src/dist/sample-soapui-project.xml" );
  runner.run(); 
}

The runner.run() call will throw an exception if an error occurs. If you want more control over your integration / error-reporting, a specific TestCase could be run as follows:

public void testTestCaseRunner() throws Exception 
{
  WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject( "src/dist/sample-soapui-project.xml" ); 
  TestSuite testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName( "Test Suite" ); 
  TestCase testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName( "Test Conversions" );

  // create empty properties and run synchronously
  TestRunner runner = testCase.run( new PropertiesMap(), false ); 
  assertEquals( Status.FINISHED, runner.getStatus() ); 
}
```

Comment: Hope it will help you :)